# How to disable coffeescript on Rails 5

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I started a new `rails 5.1.4` project but I have forgotten to add `--skip-coffee` on `rails new`.

Is there a way to remove the `coffeescript` dependency without creating a new project?.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

1. Remove or comment out `gem 'coffee-rails'` from `Gemfile`.
2. Change Javascript files that ends with `.js.coffee` to `.js`.
3. Add `config.generators.javascript_engine = :js` to your [application.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators).
4. Make sure your `tmp` cache is cleared with `rake tmp:cache:clear`

Comment: Worked in Rails 5.2.1 (I forgot to add the switch when I created the project too - duh!)

Comment: Would have never thought of clearing cache. And that did it. Thanks.

Comment: No need to change the javascript_engine generator with Rails 5.2.4.4 (I still had to clear the cache)

Comment: Just a thought - Don't you have to do a 'bundle' if you change Gemfile?