# Heroku - Build fail "LoadError: canot load such file -- coffee_script"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets

As the title states, I'm unable to complete a build on Heroku after removing `gem 'coffee-rails'` from my Gemfile.

Below is the error message as well as a few lines before that show that it is removing coffee-script.

```
remote:        Removing coffee-script (2.4.1)
remote:        Removing coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
remote:        Removing coffee-rails (4.2.2)
remote:        The latest bundler is 2.0.0.pre.3, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        LoadError: cannot load such file -- coffee_script
remote:        /tmp/build_dc46e31874491817c9a77e17cf3ac4d1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
```

To me, it looks like this could be an issue with Bootsnap on Heroku.

Steps I've taken:

1. Removed `gem 'coffee-rails'`   Ran `bundle update` .
2. Removed all references to coffee script per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871341/5491007)
3. Added, committed and pushed the updated Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to my master branch.
4. Ran `rake tmp:cache:clear` on Heroku via bash.
5. Restarted dyno

At this point, I'm tempted to just keep the gem installed as I've confirmed that the build passes.

Any assistance would be wonderful.

Edit: I have staging app setup that had this same issue. Simply starting a new staging app/remote solved the issue, so that's why I'm leaning towards a cache issue.

Comment: Try deleting `tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache` and `tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache`

Comment: @Tom Thank you - I did remove those, but they are recreated on dyno restart.

Comment: Try `heroku repo:purge_cache`

Comment: I get `repo:purge_cache is not a heroku command`

Comment: Ended up reinstalling the gem too :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had the exact same issue. As you have mentioned, the cache needs clearing. To do this

```
heroku repo:purge_cache
git push heroku master
```

If you don't have heroku repo, it's a plugin that needs to be installed. Just follow those steps mentioned in Heroku's guide [here](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache):

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
git push heroku master
```

Should work fine now
Note `heroku repo:purge_cache` without the app's name is of course enough if the remote is setup.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer.

Comment: This proved to be what we needed as well when `rake tmp:cache:clear` via Bash didn't solve the problem. Thank you!